# Icon path lookup in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, freedesktop.org

Qt supports the [icon theme lookup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#fromTheme) by returning a QIcon. But for my QML view I need the icon path instead of a QIcon. Is there a way to get either the path from the looked up icon or to do a lookup which returns the icon path? I.e. I want to put an icon name according to the [Icon Naming Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/latest/index.html#overview) into a function which returns a path to an image file.

If this is not possible with Qt, what is the next best option? Is there a library out there for the icon look up as specified in the [Freedesktop Icon Theme Sspecification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html#icon_lookup)?

Comment: You looking for this?  QStringList QIcon::themeSearchPaths()

Returns the search paths for icon themes.

Comment: Nope. I Clearified what I want to do.

Comment: I think you can find the way Qt load this icon at Qt's sources. And base on this create your own function.